# How to link all the connecting edges together in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have an [undirected graph](https://mathinsight.org/definition/undirected_graph) with nodes and edges, and the graph can have [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)).

My question is, given a list of starting node(s), how to form "lines"-- which is defined as just a list of linearly connected edge-- so that

1. All the edges must belong to at least one and only one "line". This is important because since the graph can have cycles, the edges should not go into "infinite loop"
2. All the edges in a line must be connected as per their original sequence in the graph

Take for example

[image]

Assuming that for this example, the the starting node is G and F. Then the "lines" are

1. G->C->A->B->D
2. F->C
3. A->E->D
4. E->B

Note that all the edges are covered, and only once.

Note that also, there can be many different answers which are all correct.

Also note that if the starting node is G, then G->C->F is also a "line".

Is there an algorithm ( in Boost C++ or somewhere, or .Net) that does just that?

Comment: Is  `A->B, A->C, A->E, B->D, C->F, G->C, D->E` a valid solution?

Comment: The question is not completely clear. When you say "line", do you mean what is described as a _trail_ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_and_path)? I don't understand "All the edges in a line must be connected as per their original sequence in the graph". Does this refer to the numbers you wrote over the edges?

Comment: You may be looking for what igraph's `unfold_tree()` function does. You can experiment with it in R, Python or Mathematica before you start with C. See https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_unfold_tree  See what I get with Mathematica: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLNSQ.png Here I used G as starting vertex, but additional starting vertices will only make a difference in the directions of the edges in the final result (assuming that graph was connected)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, wouldn't the list of edges, e.g. all lines consisting of exactly one edge, be a valid solution? Or are there additional requirements?

Answer (score 0):

```
- LOOP S over starting nodes
    - DFS from S. 
          - Do not revisit nodes.
          - Mark edges traversed by search
          - IF leaf reached, or deeper search stopped by visited nodes
               - OUTPUT "line" from S to leaf
    - IF all edges marked traversed, STOP
```